# Treemap last data item not showing

Tags: d3.js, treemap

I'm trying to create a treemap with d3js based on a value from the data. However if I use the hierarchy and call the sum function to sum by this value, it looks like the last item in the data is not shown in the treemap it self. If I inspect this in the browser, I can see the element is outside the treemap. [image: Last items outside the treemap]

A section of the code that I currently use, and which I think is relevant is:

```js
const margin = { top: 40, right: 20, bottom: 0, left: 0 },
    width = element.getBoundingClientRect().width,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom ,
    formatNumber = d3.format(",d")

  let  transitioning

  const x = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, width]).range([0, width]);

  const y = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, height]).range([0, height]);

  const treemap = d3.treemap()
    .size([width, height])
    .round(false)
    .padding(1)
    .paddingInner(1)
    .tile(d3.treemapSquarify.ratio(d => d))

  //
  const root = hierarchy(data, (d: any) => d.children);
        root.sum((d) => d.value ? d.value : 0)
        root.sort((a, b) => b.height - a.height || b.value - a.value )
```

I hope someone can help me out on this one, and if I need to provide more information then please let me know. Here is a codepen: https://codepen.io/Brian1410/pen/qBPMeOO

Comment: It would be helpful if you can share a live codepen/fiddle. I can definitely help debug the issue there.

Comment: @Shreshth , thanks for your reply. I've just added a codepen link to the original question

Comment: Brian, the codepen you shared doesn't display any part of the treemap, unlike in the screenshot. Sorry.